# Strange behavior with google chrome and FPS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I have coded a little engine to display 5 sprites using javascript in Canvas2D. Everything works fine and is completely optimised.

The FPS fluctuates between 30 and 60 - but the interesting thing is, it says on a constant 60 fps when the google javascript console is open!

Any body else experiencing this?

n.b. I am using requestAnimationFrame

**Edit:**

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jrPNy/1

Play Around with the "Particles" Number so your fps is around 40-50. Than open the console, and it goes up to 60 fps. (Chrome 21.0.1180.83)

Comment: Could it be a focus issue?  Chrome might deliberately lower the FPS when it thinks the page doesn't have focus, and having the console open might somehow trigger always-focused behavior.

Comment: Can't see it being a focus issue as the tab keeps the focus all the time. When focus is lost the fps goes to zero, as expected.

Comment: Do you have some code we can look at?

Comment: I worked it out it's not that I am opening the console per se, but the fact opening the console makes the window smaller which in turn makes the drawing canvas area smaller.

Comment: that is right :) you should award the bounty to you :)

Comment: looks like i cant edit this post anymore: youtube video: http://youtu.be/2FJEi_oKZiE?hd=1 chrome:gpu screen: http://imgur.com/xDY80

Comment: I have this same issue right now using webgl. When my inspector is closed, my fps jumps between 30 and 60, when the inspector is open, I get a steady 60fps. Even when I make the inspector smaller, so that it doesn't reduce the size of the canvas, I get the same result. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: That's really weird if really the FPS increases when the console is open. In my case the sample provided by JamieFearon is showing me 60fps, but I have a strong computer with Core-i7, 32GB of RAM and a Radeon 7900HD card. I saw in the @XzenTorXz video that the console is docked in the Chrome window, what happens if the console is undocked? -- Edit: Just saw the Jamie answer about the canvas smaller... this seems to be a good reason indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the question author remarked in a comment, this has to do with the visible canvas area. Opening the console reduces the height of the viewport, which on a normal-sized display means that there will be less content to render. 60 FPS is a soft limit given by the display refresh rate; doing more frames than that wouldn't make sense since it's impossible to display more than 60 frames per second on a normal monitor.

I tested this on my machine, reducing the CPU speed so that I don't always get 60FPS. In the provided Fiddle example, I had around 24FPS normally. Opening the Console reduced the visible canvas to about 60% of its original size, and the FPS increased to 30 on average. Resizing the Console would influence the FPS accordingly: with only 10% of the canvas visible, the FPS wiggled around 42, and with a very small Console and the entire canvas visible, the FPS went slightly below the original value, to 23. Increasing the CPU speed brought the FPS to a constant 60, regardless of the state of the Console.

Now, given that the JavaScript that generates the screen is still running, regardless of how much of the canvas is visible, what influences the needed processing power is the actual rendering of the canvas, and the way the canvas image is composited onto the rest of the HTML, on the browser window, and finally onto the screen. More and more of that work is moved to the GPU, so when every stage of the compositing process will be done in OpenGL, the FPS should always be maxed out.

Comment: well then we dont experience the same things, I have activated Accelerated 2D Canvas. In a game i develop right now chrome only gives me 30fps. With the console i have constant 60. And the canvas size is not smaller, neither the viewing part on the canvas. I put the console nearly visible on the bottom, so i get a smoth developement.

Comment: That's weird... So any time the console is deactivated, the framerate drops to 30, and any time it's reactivated, the FPS goes back to 60?

Comment: yes exaclty like this, its not quite the bad in the fiddle example but theres also a visible effect. I added a video so you can see what i mean.

Comment: Indeed, we're not experiencing the same thing. I even tried it on a Windows machine, and I always get a constant FPS (and `chrome:gpu` is almost identical). Can you reproduce it on a different machine?

Comment: it occurs on my laptop and desktop pc, both windows 7 64bit.

Comment: i don't see any difference on my Intel HD graphics 1000 [Chrome 22.0.1229.14 beta-m, 2000 particles]. Even when Console covers most of the screen!

Comment: It seems that different people get different behaviors, so most likely it comes down to the graphics card and its drivers. On my first test machine, I had software rendering, so the FPS dependency on the visible canvas area makes sense. On the Windows machine, I get constant FPS. Do you have any other plugins on top of the developer toolbar?

Comment: i thought it would affect more systems, because my 2 systems are very diffrent in their architecture (onboard Intel HD Graphics and nVidia Geforce 8800GT). It also happens on clean browser install (without any extensions). I opened a chromium ticket: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=144940. I will see if they can help me.

Comment: Can you check the flags on chrome:flags? Try to enable/disable things like accelerated 2D canvas, GPU VSync, Threaded compositing, and any other switches that might be related to canvas rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing with chrome on my macbook. It appears the osx dock is causing the frame rate to slow down, when you open the console the viewport is moved away far enough from the dock for the frame rate to go back up to 60fps. If you move the window away from the dock the frame rate goes up. You can have 60fps fullscreen without the console open if you autohide the dock.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to this that worked for me was using this function

```
//Don't change these variable names
const times = [];
let fps;

//Replace refreshLoop with the name of your animation loop
function refreshLoop() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    const now = performance.now();
    while (times.length > 0 && times[0] <= now - 1000) {
      times.shift();
    }
    times.push(now);
    fps = times.length;
    //Replace refreshLoop with your animation loop here as well
    refreshLoop();
  });
}
//Don't forget to call it again here if you haven't!
refreshLoop();
```

NOTE: When switching tabs, low FPS will occur. When you switch back to the tab that shows FPS, it will increase until the actual fps matches. This won't affect the performance display itself.

Answer (score -1):

Google chrome uses vsync meaning it will limit the FPS to you'r screen FPS limit, Most screens are 60 FPS so you'r google will match that if possible but will not go above it. There might be a program to remove the vsync but i know that Nvidia drivers can control this but you will need a GTX 610 or hight to do this